# Handling traversal in Zope2 product

Tags: zope

I want to create a simple Zope2 product that implements a "virtual" folder where a part of the path is processed by my code. A URI of the form

```
/members/$id/view
```

e.g.

```
/members/isaacnewton/view
```

should be handled by code in the /members object, i.e. a method like `members.view(id='isaacnewton')`.

The Zope TTW Python scripts have `traverse_subpath` but I have no idea how to do this in my product code.

I have looked at the `IPublishTraverse` interface `publishTraverse()` but it seems very generic.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still the easiest way is to use the `__before_publishing_traverse__` hook on the `members` object:

```
from zExceptions import Redirect


def __before_publishing_traverse__(self, object, request):
    stack = request.TraversalRequestNameStack
    if len(stack) > 1 and stack[-2] == 'view':
        try:
            self.request.form['member_id'] = stack.pop(-1)
            if not validate(self.request['member_id']):
                raise ValueError
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            # missing context or not an integer id; perhaps some URL hacking going on?
            raise Redirect(self.absolute_url())  # redirects to `/members`, adjust as needed
```

This method is called by the publisher before traversing further; so the publisher has already located the `members` object, and this method is passed itself (`object`), and the request. On the request you'll find the traversal stack; in your example case that'll hold `['view', 'isaacnewton']` and this method moves `'isaacnewton'` to the request under the key `'member_id'` (after an optional validation).

When this method returns, the publisher will use the *remaining* stack to continue the traverse, so it'll now traverse to `view`, which should be a browser view that expects a `member_id` key in the request. It then can do it's work:

```
class MemberView(BrowserView):
    def __call__(self):
        if 'member_id' in self.request.form:  # Huzzah, the traversal worked!
```

Comment: This looks like a nicer interface than publishTraverse(), especially having access to the full traversal stack in one call. I'll try this.

Comment: One small problem, the TraversalRequestNameStack list has reverse order (at least in Zope 2.13): `stack = ['view', 'isaacnewton']`. So the test should be `stack[0] == 'view'` and in the try `stack.pop(1)`.

Comment: @robcast: Sorry, yes, my mistake actually. I misread older code I used as a quick reference for the method. The name was a hint, of course; stack order is usually reversed. :-)